# Different background image for different pages in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image, fullscreen

**Hi good morning stackers,**
I need your help with my **Twitter Bootstrap** page, site is not onepage scrolling neither horizontal nor vertical. The following problem: I have several pages this means index.html - work.html - about.html etc. I would like to have a fullscreen background image for each page. What opportunities are there? into CSS? or include on any page. **So please help me to solve my problem**

Answer (score 2):

A common way to identify pages in CSS is mark the `<body>` element with different ids or classes.

frontpage.html:

```
<body id="page-front">
```

news.html:

```
<body id="page-news">
```

Then you can discriminate with different background in CSS:

```
#page-front { background: white url('koala.jpg'); }
#page-news { background: red url('blackmamba.jpg'); }
```

[For an actual Bootstrap theme example you can look at here (mini logo not visible on the front age)](https://github.com/miohtama/bootstrap-theme-libertymusicstore/blob/master/less/libertymusicstore.less#L593)

Comment: Thank's for this quick answer Mikko. Are there any other solution proposals?

Comment: I am quite confident my way is the best practice of the web development community. You need to message to your CSS which page/template you are rendering. There is only one way to do this.